# Multitexture rendering (glActiveTexture beyong GL_TEXTURE0) not working

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, rendering, textures

I have been trying to send more than one textures to my shader using sampler2D array + glActiveTexture().
The first texture sent with GL_TEXTURE0 & sampler2D array with index 0 comes out fine. However, the second texture does not render (repeats 1st texture).
I have been websearching for a solution to no avail up to this point.
So, here I am.

It'll be greatly appreciated if you could lend a hand. And please let me know if you need any other info.

Here are some of the things I have tried to debug this.

1. Switching the enums, GL_TEXTURE0 and GL_TEXTURE1, result in only rendering what used to be the second texture (head2.png). This makes me believe my texture file parsing is working properly.
2. glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) after glActiveTexture won't solve the problem.
3. Made sure the texture ID that I send as floats are grabbing the correct indices. e.g. color = aa[int(tid)] with aa being an array of vec4 with different coloring.
4. Even if I hard code the index in the shader, it won't show the second texture. As a matter of fact, all 32 indices will always show the first texture.

Below is my main file and some of the methods used.

- main.cxx

```
// C++
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>

// OpenGL
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <FreeImage.h>

// Custom
#include "window.h"
#include "math.h"
#include "shader.h"

#include "texture.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace JDEngine;


int main()
{
    Window window("Test", 800, 800);
    window.SetClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);


    Shader* shader =  new Shader("src/shaders/testvert.shader", "src/shaders/testfrag.shader");

    shader->Enable();
    shader->SetUniformMat4("pr_matrix", Mat4::Orthographic(-4,4,-4,4,-4,4));
    shader->Disable();


    GLfloat data[24] = {0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0, -1,-1,0,-1,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0};
    GLfloat uv[16] = {0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1, 0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1};
    GLfloat tid[8] = {0,0,0,0, 1,1,1,1}; // 0s going into GL_TEXTURE0, 1s to GL_TEXTURE1
    GLuint ind[12] = {0,1,2,2,1,3, 4,5,6,6,5,7};


    // For buffers & vertices
    GLuint vao, vbo, vbouv, vbotid, ibo;
    Texture* tex1 = new Texture("data/body2.png"); // yellow square
    Texture* tex2 = new Texture("data/head2.png"); // blue square
    cout << endl << tex1->GetTID() << " " << tex2->GetTID(); // spits out "1 2"

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);    // Vertex Array Object
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);         // Vertex Buffer Object
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(data), data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);


    glGenBuffers(1, &vbouv);         // Vertex Buffer Object
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbouv);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(uv), uv, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);


    glGenBuffers(1, &vbotid);         // Vertex Buffer Object
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbotid);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(tid), tid, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GLfloat), 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glBindVertexArray(0);

    glGenBuffers(1, &ibo);         // Index Buffer Object
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(ind), ind, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);




    //glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    while (!window.ShouldClose())
    {
        window.Clear();
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        // *********************************************************************
        shader->Enable();
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex1->GetTID());

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex2->GetTID());

        glBindVertexArray(vao);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 12, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr); // seeing two yellow squares (GL_TEXTURE0 worked but not 1)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
        // *********************************************************************
        window.Update();
    }
    window.Close();
    return 0;
}
```

- texture.cxx

```
#include "texture.h"
namespace JDEngine
{
    // ********************************************************************
    Texture::Texture(const string& filename)
    : mFileName(filename)
    {
        mTID = Load();
    }
    // ********************************************************************
    GLuint Texture::Load()
    {
        BYTE* pixels = LoadImage(mFileName.c_str(), &mWidth, &mHeight);

        GLuint result;
        glGenTextures(1, &result);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, result);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, mWidth, mHeight, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

        free(pixels);

        return result;
    }
    // ********************************************************************
}
```

- testfrag.shader

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) out vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D textures[32];

in DATA
{
    vec4 pos;
    vec2 uv;
    float tid;
} fs_in;

void main()
{
    color = texture(textures[int(fs_in.tid + 0.5)], fs_in.uv);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`textures[int(fs_in.tid + 0.5)]` is undefined behavior, because `textures` is of type `sampler2D` and `fs_in.tid` is a fragment shader input and not a [Dynamically uniform expression](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Core_Language_(GLSL)#Dynamically_uniform_expression).

See [OpenGL Shading Language 4.60 Specification - 4.1.7. Opaque Types](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#opaque-types)

> Texture-combined sampler types are opaque types, declared and behaving as described above for opaque types. When aggregated into arrays within a shader, they can only be indexed with a dynamically uniform integral expression, otherwise results are undefined. [...]

---

I recommend to use `sampler2DArray` (see [Sampler](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL))) rather than an array of `sampler2D`.
When you use a `sampler2DArray`, then you don't need any indexing at all, because  the "index" is encoded in the 3rd component of the texture coordinate at texture lookup (see [`texture`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/texture.xhtml)).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Maybe I should indeed look for 2Darray.
However, I did try to use a hardcoded index in my shader. But this did not solve the issue (only saw yellow boxes even when I used the index for blue). Does this also fall into your explanation? e.g. not being a uniform integer expression?

Comment: Where do you assign the texture unit indices to the texture sampler uniform?

Comment: I swapped out color = texture(textures[...]) with texture(textures[1]) for example.